# Can't import module in Spyder, not sure how to use sys.path

Tags: python, import, module, spyder

Context: Using Spyder on Windows 10, less than 3 months learning Python.

I have been cruising along with Python Crash Course the last couple weeks, and got to a part where I am supposed to import a module. I created a module called car.py and tried to import it in a file called my_car.py .

The book says to import the module to enter:

```
from car import car
```

which doesn't work.

```
import car
```

also doesn't work

I either get `cannot import name 'car'`, or `name 'Car' is not defined`.

Also tried this...

```
Export PYTHONPATH ="${PYTHONPATH}:\Users\Alex\Documents\Python_scripts\Py_Crash\Classes\Inheritance "
```

I have looked through stack overflow, and spent a couple hours trying to figure it out, but am confused about what to do. Here is what I found on Stackoverflow which seems pertinent:

> Set the environment variable PYTHONPATH to a colon-separated list of
>   directories to search for imported modules. In your program, use
>   sys.path.append('/path/to/search') to add the names of directories you
>   want Python to search for imported modules. sys.path is just the list
>   of directories Python searches every time it gets asked to import a
>   module, and you can alter it as needed (although I wouldn't recommend
>   removing any of the standard directories!). Any directories you put in
>   the environment variable PYTHONPATH will be inserted into sys.path
>   when Python starts up. Use site.addsitedir to add a directory to
>   sys.path. The difference between this and just plain appending is that
>   when you use addsitedir, it also looks for .pth files within that
>   directory and uses them to possibly add additional directories to
>   sys.path based on the contents of the files. See the documentation for
>   more detail.

```
#my_car.py
"""
 os.path.join("foo", "bar", "baz")
'foo/bar/baz'
 os.path.split(_)
('foo/bar', 'baz')

from car import car 

my_new_car = Car('audi', 'a4', 2016)
print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())

my_new_car.odometer_reading = 23
my_new_car.read_odometer()

#car.py
"""A class that can be used to represent a car"""

class Car():
    """A simple attempt to represent a car"""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()

    def read_odometer(self):
        print("This car has " + str(self.odomter_reading) + "miles on it.")

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
       if mileage >= self.odomoter_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage

        else:
            print("You can't roll back an odomter!")


    def increment_odomter(self, miles):
        self.odomoter_reading += miles
```

I guess I am confused about where I am supposed to set the new path, and also what to actually enter. Can I use spyder to do this, or do I need to use python command line, or my computers command line?

Comment: Please post the contents of `car.py`.  Also, are  `car.py`, and `my_car.py` in the same directory?

Comment: @Gerrat So, they are in the same directory according to using            
    (import os)

  ( os.getcwd() )                                                                                            Both resulted in C:\\Users\\Alex                                                              Also, posted car.py and my_car.py

Comment: Some advice.  Don't concatenate multiple files together in a post.  Post each separately, so its more obvious they are in fact separate files.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for importing a name from another [module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#modules) is just in the form:

```
from <name of .py file without the extension> import <case-sensitive name of variable you want to import from that file>
```

eg.

```
from car import Car
```

When they're in the same directory, you don't need to do anything with the `PYTHONPATH`, or search path.